# typescript type is not respected in promise catch

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would expect this code not to work because the `insertObj` function is declared to return an object of type MyObject (wrapped in a Promise) but if the `catch` clause is executed it will actually return null. Why does this work and doesn't throw any exception (both in my code and in the typescript repl)?

```
class MyObject {
  myField = ''
}

type z = typeof MyObject;

type Persister<T> = {
  create:(a: any) =>  T;
  save: (a: MyObject) => Promise<MyObject>
}

type DataSource = {
  getRepository: (obj: typeof MyObject) =>  Persister<MyObject>
}
let dataSource: DataSource;

async function insertObj(name: string): Promise<MyObject> {
    const appRepo = dataSource.getRepository(MyObject);
    let obj: (MyObject | null) = appRepo.create({ name });

    await appRepo.save(obj)
        .then(res => {
            obj = res;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            obj = null;
        });
    return obj;
}
```

PS: note that if I change the function to this, it raises a "not assignable" exception on the `return` clause as expected. I would expect these two forms to be equivalent, what am I missing?

```
async function insertObj(name: string): Promise<MyObject> {
    const appRepo = dataSource.getRepository(MyObject);
    let obj: (MyObject | null) = appRepo.create({ name });

    try {
        obj = await appRepo.save(obj);
    } catch(err) {
        obj = null;
    }
            
    return obj;
```

Comment: TS cannot follow arbitrary state changes to closed-over variables.  See [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and the answer to the linked question above.

Comment: Ok I see. I read the github discussion and that makes sense. At some point someone mentions that the biggest issue with this design limitation is in promise callbacks. As promises are part of the js specifications and ts is made to understand js and integrate it, why can't the ts compiler detect when the callback is used inside an awaited Promise constructor (or inside a then / catch clause, which is essentially the same) and enforce stricter code flow analysis in that case?

Comment: Presumably for the reasons discussed in ms/TS#9998. I don't think I have any further insight than that, nor do I know of any more authoritative answer than that.